# CSS (text-overflow: ellipsis) -- a shorter way?

Tags: css

Is there a shorter way to for text ellipsis? Just a gripe, but doesn't it seem like it should only require at most, width and text-overflow?

```
width: (whatever);
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Nope, what you have there is the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text-overflow property in CSS deals with situations where text is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It can be clipped (i.e. cut off, hidden), display an ellipsis `('…', Unicode Range Value U+2026) or display an author-defined string (no current browser support for author-defined strings).`

Note that text-overflow only occurs when the container's overflow property has the value `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto` and `white-space: nowrap;`.

```css
.overflow {
  width: 10em;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  /**
   * Required properties to achieve text-overflow
   */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body style {
  display: block;
  font: 14px monospace;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<style>
  .clip {
    text-overflow: clip;
  }
</style>
<p class="overflow clip">This is an example text showing nothing interesting but the truncated content via text-overflow shorthand property.</p>

<style>
  .ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
<p class="overflow ellipsis">This is an example text showing nothing interesting but the truncated content via text-overflow shorthand property.</p>

<style>
  .word {
    text-overflow: ellipsis-word;
  }
</style>
<p class="overflow word">This is an example text showing nothing interesting but the truncated content via text-overflow shorthand property.</p>

<style>
  .text {
    text-overflow: "---";
  }
</style>
<p class="overflow text">This is an example text showing nothing interesting but the truncated content via text-overflow shorthand property.</p>

<style>
  .double {
    text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<p class="overflow double">This is an example text showing nothing interesting but the truncated content via text-overflow shorthand property.</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

All that is *necessary* for text ellipsis is the following three rules:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

With those rules text-ellipsis will work **if the containing element is shrunk due to a parent element whose width is smaller than the text content**. `white-space: nowrap;` is integral as normal behavior is to break text on whitespace to contain it within it's parent. Preventing this behavior with `nowrap` will force the text to remain on a single line, potentially overflowing it's parent.

You *can* add width to the containing element to be more precise, but as stated above, it's not necessary.

**Shorten with a CSS Preprocessor**

The rules can be simplified into a mixin that will make setting these rules simple. E.g. in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/):

```
// declare mixin
.text-ellipsis() {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

// use it
div {
  width: 50px;
  .text-ellipsis;
}
```